# Could not open pop-up oAuth authentication in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, oauth, popup

I'm using this great library to make oauth authentication :

```
https://oauth.io/docs/mobiles
```

and by this code (written in router function) :

```
OAuth.initialize('FUxf14**YBrE');
//Using popup (option 1)
  OAuth.popup('instagram', function(error, result) {
    //handle error with error
    //use result.access_token in your API request
      console.log(error);
  });
```

This code should open a pop-up but console.log(error) tell me:

```
message: "Could not open a popup"
```

Why it can't open a pop-up?

Answer (score 1):

The popup is probably blocked by the browser.

To prevent that, make the call to `OAuth.popup` only inside a `click` event handler.